# NodeJS Postgres switch working schema

Tags: node.js, postgresql, schema

I'm trying to connect to my postgres database.

Everything is working fine, but in my database I've got 2 schemas. One of them is created by default by [`PgAdmin`](https://www.pgadmin.org) (`public`), and the second one, `ZTB`, which I have created.

When I connect to my database using NodeJS, it by default connects to the "`public`" schema, and therefore I cannot query tables from "ZTB".

Is there any solution to switch the current working schema in the NodeJS server?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, Rafael. Here's your guide on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you tell us which PG module you are using and the connection string you are forming? Relevant snippets of your implementation will help us help you.

Comment: `set search_path ...` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html#idm46428672049392

Comment: I resolved it myself.  ``client.query("SET search_path TO 'ZTB';");`` did the job.
Update: exactly as @a_horse_with_no_name said.

Comment: @Rafael can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution myself - `client.query("SET search_path TO 'ZTB';");` did the job exactly as @a_horse_with_no_name said later.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change your schema name to lower case. Having upper case may create problems.

Next, whatever you want to query just do [your schema name].[your table name], and you should be fine.

```
client.query("select * from ztb.[your table name]"))
```

Comment: Thanks for response but this is not an answer for my question and it was resolved almost 2 years ago. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), then choosing the schema is available right out of the box.

Within [Initialization Options](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html), there is option `schema` that supports flexible values:

```js
const pgp = require('pg-promise')({
    schema: ['public', 'ZTB'] // access tables from "public" + "ZTB"
});
```

And you can set `schema` even to a function that returns the schema(s).